# JS/Redux Ternary operation explaination

Tags: javascript, redux

Could you please explain how this part of code is working? Im folowing course and im stuck on it:

```
 const getVisibleExpenses = (expenses, {text, sortBy, startDate, endDate}) => {
  return expenses.filter((expense)=> {
    const startDateMatch = typeof startDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= startDate;
```

So we are destructing stuff here {text, sortBy ... } but, i got problem with understanding what is done with that part:

```
    const startDateMatch = typeof startDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= startDate;
```

Comment: (That's not a ternary expression.)

Comment: You can see an explanation of actual ternary expressions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 2):

> i got problem with understanding what is done with that part:
>
> ```
> const startDateMatch = typeof startDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= startDate;
> ```

`startDateMatch` is set to the result of the expression `typeof startDate !== 'number' || expense.createdAt >= startDate`, which is:

- `typeof startDate !== 'number'` - will be `true` if the type of `startDate` is **not** `"number"`, or false if it **is** `"number"`
- `||` - logical OR
- `expense.createdAt >= startDate` - will be `true` if `expense.createdAt` is greater than or equal to `startDate`

So `startDateMatch` will be set to `true` if the type of `startDate` is not `"number"` **or** `expense.createdAt` is greater than or equal to `startDate`; it will be set to `false` otherwise.

---

Just as a side note, that's not a ternary operation (an operation with three operands). It's a set of three binary operations (operations with two operands):

1. `typeof startDate !== 'number'` - the operands are `typeof startDate` and `'number'`, the operator is `!==`
2. `expense.createdAt >= startDate` - the operands are `expense.createdAt` and `startDate`, the operator is `>=`.
3. `(result of 1) || (result of 2)` - the operands are the results of the two above (which are not evaluated in that order), the operator is `||`

`||` works like this:

1. It evaluates its left-hand operand
2. If the result from #1 is *truthy*, takes that truthy value as its result
3. If the result from #1 is *falsy*, `||` evaluates its right-hand operand and takes that result as its value

*(A* truthy *value is a value that isn't* falsy*. A* falsy *value is a value that evaluates to `false` in conditions. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `false`, and [on browsers] `document.all` for historical reasons. All other values are truthy.)*

JavaScript does have one ternary operator (for now), the *conditional* operator (`? :`).

Comment: Thank you very much TJ!

Comment: I've been around plenty long enough to know what `document.all` was but I missed the update that made that falsy.  It makes sense and it's good to know.  Thanks!